# Does "whether" need "or not" at the end here?

Tags: conditional-constructions, negation

Should i add "or not" after this sentence ?

> I want to know whether you would publish the results today.

> I want to know whether you would publish the results today or not.

Comment: Please add some more detail explaining why you think the sentence may be wrong, or which version you think may be correct, and why.  Otherwise "proofreading" questions are routinely closed.

Comment: Also it's good style to keep the "or not" close to the "whether", if possible.  "I want to know **whether or not** you would ..."  This helps the reader better understand the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may grammatically say:

"I want to know whether you will publish the results today or not."

"I want to know whether you will publish the results today."

"I want to know whether or not you will publish the results today."

Stylistically, the second is more succinct than the third, but the third requires less parsing by the recipient. The first is neither as succinct as the second nor as easy to parse as the third. I see no advantage in the first form, but will admit that it comes up fairly frequently in speech or informal writing. The third is the most idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

No; despite what you might have read here to the contrary, never.

The whole point of using "whether" instead of "if" or anything else is that "whether" necessarily includes "or not."

Although many people make the mistake of using "whether or not", in fact that is in no way different from "whether" by itself. Is that much clear?

"Please let me know *whether* you would like a place/ticket/whatever…" requires a response either way. "No, thanks…" just as much as "Yes, please…".

"Please let me know *if* you would like (whatever)…" requires no response from anyone who doesn't want one… "Yes, I would…" matters. "No, thanks…" is wholly superfluous.